# select items from one table with sum of records matching HAVING in subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have a table of cities with, among other things, population, latitude and longitude. I also have a table of airports with various info including latitude and longitude.

A query like this roughly obtains the population of all towns within 100 km of a given latitude and longitude:

```
SELECT SUM(cty_population) as cty_population_total FROM
(SELECT
  cty_population, (
    6371 * acos (
      cos ( radians(37.61899948) )
      * cos( radians( cty_latitude ) )
      * cos( radians( cty_longitude ) - radians(-122.37500000) )
      + sin ( radians(37.61899948) )
      * sin( radians( cty_latitude ) )
    )
  ) AS cty_distance
FROM cities
HAVING cty_distance < 100) cty_population_alias
```

This will give a result like this:

```
cty_population_total
6541221
```

In the above query, **37.61899948** is the latitude and **-122.37500000** is the longitude.

My question is: can I select an arbitrary number of airports from the airports table, pass their longitudes and latitudes into this subquery in place of the above numbers, and find the city population within 100 km of each airport. Ideally I would have results like this:

```
airport_name     airport_pop    
Boston Logan         6654901
London Heathrow     11345690
```

...etc.

I could do this with scripting, but I am wondering if it can be done with SQL alone? The database engine is MySQL.

Comment: Is there a reason you used `HAVING` instead of `WHERE` there ?

Comment: WHERE throws the error: "Unknown column 'cty_distance' in 'where clause'". As far as I knew, you have to use HAVING with an alias.

Comment: It's just odd to see a `HAVING` without a `GROUP BY` I would have personally done something like `WHERE (distance calculation here) < 100` but that's just me.

Comment: @apokryfos, I'd have used a derived table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a very procedural way of thinking this which would not work well in SQL. You can think of it as joining the city with all its nearby airports.

The following may work:

```
SELECT a.name, SUM(c.cty_population) 
FROM cities c JOIN airports a ON (
6371 * acos (
  cos ( radians(a.latitude) )
  * cos( radians( c.cty_latitude ) )
  * cos( radians( c.cty_longitude ) - radians(a.longitude) )
  + sin ( radians(a.latitude) )
  * sin( radians( c.cty_latitude ) )
) < 100
WHERE (filter airports or something else here)
GROUP BY a.airport_id, a.name
```

Also, I suggest you migrate to MySQL 5.7 which includes spatial functions and data types built in.

Comment: Thanks for the responses and the 5.7 tip. One note: the above does not seem to return a SUM of population. Rather, it returns all the cities' populations near the airport, individually.

Comment: I seem to have achieved it by adding the SUM around c.cty_population, and adding GROUP BY airport id.

Comment: Updated: I'm also grouping by `a.name` which may appear to be redundant but is recommended to include all non-aggregated display columns in the grouping.